# Generate pdf from jupyter notebook without code

Tags: pandas, jupyter, ipython

I have a Jupyter notebook that contains markdown, code, and outputs (graphs). I would like to generate PDF from this notebook.

I tried to hide code using HTML code which I get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer) then I tried to download it as pdf but again code shows up. But when I download it as HTML it don't show any code but again when I tried to convert HTML to pdf it again shows code.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True  my_notebook.ipynb
```

This also works for html output.
You will find the documentation for this and other options [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html?highlight=TemplateExporter.exclude).

FYI, for complex notebooks, this may generate errors depending on your version of nbconvert, LaTeX and other components. In that case try to convert to html then print to pdf using a browser.

Comment: It is good solution. but this approch break markdown like heading shows up as # heading etc. each markdown line contains some unwanted section number like 0.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are working with Qt Console (anaconda):

Install Jupiter extensions:

```
!pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

Enable nbextension:

```
!jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/main
```

Install pyppeteer:

```
!python -m pip install -U notebook-as-pdf

!pyppeteer-install
```

MAKE SURE YOUR WORKING DIRECTORY IS WHERE YOUR `Untitled.ipynb` FILE IS SAVED
Save file to HTML format without codes:

!jupyter nbconvert Untitled.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt --to html

EXPORT TO PDF FORMAT:

```
!jupyter-nbconvert Untitled.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt --to pdfviahtml
```

PS. Exporting HTML and PDF format are mutually exclusive commands, you can use either.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... No latex neccessary. Thank you

Comment: Looks like this method no longer works because the last step (`!jupyter-nbconvert Untitled.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt --to pdfviahtml`) produces an error: `PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: PdfFileWriter is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfWriter instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Make your program *generate* markdown output (you can save images and add references to them) and convert it using pandoc. Or don't convert, upload directly to Gitlab or Github and view.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link. It is the easiest and legitimate way of downloading jupyter notebook as pdf. No third party app or converter needed.

https://youtu.be/Q1J7MpI5PQk

Comment: please summarize the contents from the link to make the answer self-contained. link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the linked video does not answer the question. It shows someone printing their notebook as a pdf, so the code is inevitably included.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually create the PDF, there is a simpler solution: add the following code block & execute it

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML('<style>.input, .jp-InputArea {display: none !important}</style>')
```

Code will disappear both in the "normal" UI and in print preview / export to HTML. Open print preview, generate the PDF - it looks great now, clear the output of this one cell to bring the code back, done